# sql normalisation

Tags: database-design

I have 4 tables, courts, divisions, addresses and telephone_numbers.

Each court may have one or more divisions, civil, criminal, family etc. Each of these combination's may have one or more addresses i.e. the civil division for a particular court may or may not be at a different physical address to the criminal court. The same applies to the telephone numbers, they may be the same for each division or address, or they may be different.

I have considered several approaches to this, but do not know the best to use?

a) I could have one big table, which would replicate much of the data many times.

b) I have considered holding the FK of the court in the division table, and the FK of the division in the address table. This means duplicating division values for each court in the division table. I'm then not sure what to do with the telephone table.

c) My final though was to have a single link table holding the FK's all all 4 other tables. This would mean no replication of data, but would mean a lot of joins to get anything meaningful out, and would probably be unwieldy to use.

I'm sure I'm overlooking the obvious here, but what is the best way to model these tables?

The tables will be accessed through CakePHP, but perhaps we'll leave that to one side for the moment.

Comment: there are already plenty of SO questions and internet pages on "noramlisation" !

Comment: I'm sorry, I though people came here when they needed help? I *have* read up on normalisation which is why I am trying to produce a schema which will not duplicate data. Perhaps the next time you ask a question people will tell you that there are lots of pages already out there!

Answer (score 1):

If you will have less than 10,000 rows counting all combinations of the four tables I would suggest just a flat single table structure.  The data size would be around 80 meg if the row size was about 8K.  Most free or low cost databases will hold that much in memory and place your I/O cost to near zero.

If you feel you want multiple tables then here is a design that should give you flexibility to expand your design.  You would add application specific columns to the tables shown.
[image]

The TypeList table could hold the types of courts such as State, Federal, Local with the entries being keyed by the TL_Table value of "Court".  The list of divisions would be stored here with the TL_Type of "Division". Using the TL_Type one could populate the drop down list for data entry.  The type list for telephone numbers might be on-call, fax, primary, front desk, clerk, sherrif, etc.

Which ever way you decide I am sure someone will have a screaming negative comment but if it works they will just be screeming in space.

Comment: Thanks for the schema, I appreciate the work you've done. I do like the TypelList functionality. So if I were to use this layout, and I waned to link a court, division and its address with telephone number to a case file, which keys would I need?

Comment: I am quessing that a case does not exist in many courts or under many different divisions so it is really a 1 to 1 with each of the court, division, address and phone.  When a case comes in one could have a single table with caseid then four foreign keys to the id for court dividsion address and phone.  The "case" table would be the same for either the "one big table" or the diagram above.

Answer (score 0):

what you describe is a star schema and is the advised way to do it

```
court 1:m divisions
divisions 1:m addresses
address 1:m  telephone
```

i think you should look at what queries you need to do to get the data out as you need it although just a description not sql would be the first step

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, I think its more like court 1:m divisions, divisions 1:m addresses, divisions 1:m telephone. I have looked at star schemas and using a fact table and multiple dimension tables is much like my option c above. What I would then need to do is to link a row from the fact table to my main record as the main record needs to reference a court, its division, address and telephone number. Is this way to to go as I've not seen any examples that use the fact table in this way?